# My $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action... not executing

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

i have in my view:

```
 <% foreach (var trainingModule in Model.TrainingModules) %>
      <% {  %>
      <tr>
        <td>Training Module</td>
        <td><%: trainingModule.title %></td>
        <td>
           <a href="javascript:ResetModule(<%: Model.User.UserId %>,<%: trainingModule.userTrainingModuleId %>);" class="button">Reset Module</a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
 <% } %>
```

and:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function ResetModule(userId, userScormModuleId)
 {
   ans=window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reset this training module?');                     
   if (ans==true)
   {
     var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("ResetModule", "Manage", new { area = "User" }) %>?userId= " + userId + " &value=" + userScormModuleId, function (data) {
     });
   }
   else
   {

   }
 }
```

then in my controller i have:

```
[HttpGet]
[NoCache]
public JsonResult ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId)
{
    ZincService.ResetModule(id, userScormModuleId);
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //return RedirectToAction("UserDetails", new { id = id});
}
```

what am i doing wrong please? My action is not executing
Thanks

Comment: have you made sure that the url in your request is correct?

Comment: that is what i dont know, i dont know if i have everythin correct. the view in my controller is ResetModule, it is in the ManageController and in the User area, the rest i am not sure about

Comment: Well one obvious mistake is that you have `userId` in your JavaScript while generating URL and your action is expecting `id` parameter - if the mapping is not set in the routing than the action will not be found because of parameters mismatch. Please check that first.

Answer (score 0):

In public JsonResult ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId),

the id should be userId and userScormModuleId should be value